# React inputs: adding value in case of empty input

Tags: reactjs, input

In this example, this input appears if the state of another component is set to true. The value of the input comes from that component's state score4: "", which is passed as props newScore4. However, if the input doesn't appear and nothing is written on it, the value is not set as integer and when I add all the scores, the result I get is NaN. Is there a way to set value to 0, if the input is empty?

```
<input id="score4" type="number" min="0" max="10" name="score4" style={this.props.addJudges ? none : display} value={this.props.newScore4} onChange={this.props.handleInputChange} />
```

```
handleInputChange = (e) => {
        this.setState({...this.state,
        [e.target.name]: e.target.value})
      };
```

Comment: does `[e.target.name]: e.target.value || 0` work?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the ternary operator for that, Check if the `this.props.newScore4` is empty if it is assign a value `0` to it , if it isn't empty just assign `this.props.newScore4`

```
<input id="score4" type="number" min="0" max="10" name="score4" style={this.props.addJudges ? none : display} value={this.props.newScore4===''?0:this.props.newScore4} onChange={this.props.handleInputChange} />
```